# How to run SUMO python traci script on OMNEST using viens

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I am working on SUMO VEINS and OMNEST.
To run sumo files on OMNEST, the input of sumo files (.xml) are inputted in veins_launchd, which in turn finds an unused port, starts sumo and bridges the connection between sumo and OMNEST.

I want to control the vehicle's behavior (Speed change) on real time (during the simulation).
For this purpose, I have written a Traci script in python language, which calls sumo config file and controls vehicle speed on real time

My issue is,
**I do not know how to make this Traci script (python) to run on OMNEST via veins**.
Where should I give this python file as input so that I can visualize the output in OMNEST.
My working environment is Linux

Based on some research, I figured out 2 methods.

**1. TraCIScenarioManager module**

**2. Veins_Python**

**Method1:**  I understood by using  TraCIScenarioManager module, OMNEST can directly connect to the running sumo.
But I don't know where should I make the necessary changes inside veins module to use TraCIScenarioManager instead TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd

**Method2:** Regarding veins_python, I downloaded the source file from github and did the configuration steps as mentioned.
I used windows10 and
**Versions:** Veins5.0, OMNeT++ 5.5.1 and Python3.6
But I got the below error while configuring Veins_Python.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovpuw.png)

I also tried with the recent versions of software on windows 10
**Versions:** Veins5.2, OMNEST-5.6.2 and Python3.10
Still I get the same error.

**My Sumo Traci script is**

```
import traci
import time
import traci.constants as tc
import pytz
import datetime
from random import randrange
import pandas as pd


def getdatetime():
        utc_now = pytz.utc.localize(datetime.datetime.utcnow())
        currentDT = utc_now.astimezone(pytz.timezone("Asia/Tokyo"))
        DATIME = currentDT.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        return DATIME

def flatten_list(_2d_list):
    flat_list = []
    for element in _2d_list:
        if type(element) is list:
            for item in element:
                flat_list.append(item)
        else:
            flat_list.append(element)
    return flat_list


sumoCmd = ["sumo-gui", "-c", "osm.sumocfg"]
traci.start(sumoCmd)

packVehicleData = []
packTLSData = []
packBigData = []

while traci.simulation.getMinExpectedNumber() > 0:
       
        traci.simulationStep();
        timestep = traci.simulation.getTime()

        vehicles=traci.vehicle.getIDList();
        trafficlights=traci.trafficlight.getIDList();

        for i in range(0,len(vehicles)):

                vehid = vehicles[i]
                x, y = traci.vehicle.getPosition(vehicles[i])
                coord = [x, y]
                lon, lat = traci.simulation.convertGeo(x, y)
                gpscoord = [lon, lat]
                spd = round(traci.vehicle.getSpeed(vehicles[i])*3.6,2)


                #Packing of all the data for export to CSV/XLSX
                vehList = [getdatetime(), vehid, coord, gpscoord, spd]
                
                
                print("Vehicle: ", vehicles[i], " at datetime: ", getdatetime())
                print(vehicles[i], " >>> Position: ", coord, " | GPS Position: ", gpscoord, " |", \
                                       " Speed: ", round(traci.vehicle.getSpeed(vehicles[i])*3.6,2), "km/h |", \

                       )


                #Pack Simulated Data
                packBigDataLine = flatten_list([vehList, tlsList])
                packBigData.append(packBigDataLine)


                ##----- CONTROL Vehicles ----##

                #***SET FUNCTION FOR VEHICLES***
                #REF: https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/TraCI/Change_Vehicle_State.html
                NEWSPEED = 15 # value in m/s (15 m/s = 54 km/hr)
                if vehicles[i]=='veh2':

                        traci.vehicle.setSpeedMode('veh2',0)
                        traci.vehicle.setSpeed('veh2',NEWSPEED)
                                                                    

traci.close()

#Generate Excel file
columnnames = ['dateandtime', 'vehid', 'coord', 'gpscoord', 'spd'] 
dataset = pd.DataFrame(packBigData, index=None, columns=columnnames)
dataset.to_excel("output.xlsx", index=False)
time.sleep(5)
```

It would be really helpful if you could suggest me the procedure or tutorial for executing my Sumo's traci script on OMNEST using veins.

Comment: Your error message is not visible. Could you try again to add the link / image?

Comment: I have reuploaded the image file. Could you please check now.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is not possible since traci supports only a single client (which is veins in your setup) or if you want multiple clients veins needs to be changed. You might try to send the messages inside veins though, see [How to access TraCI command interface from TraCIDemoRSU11p in Veins Car2X simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35790944/how-to-access-traci-command-interface-from-tracidemorsu11p-in-veins-car2x-simula)